# if statement unintentionally prematurely terminated a for loop(Regex)

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to make sure that the first letters of the forename and surname strings are capital. I have some java code as follows and for the life of me I do not know why it only works on the first character in the stringbuffer and wont carry out the rest of the loop. I believe this is an error in my regex which i'm not quite clear on.

I'm 90% sure it's because of the space & colon presents in the original string.

the original string reads as

```
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer(forename + ", " + surname);
```

Java

```
int length_of_names = Director.getSurname().length() + Director.getForename().length() + 2;    
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b([A-Z][a-z]*)\\b");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(output.append(Director));


            for(int i = 0; i < length_of_names; i++)
            {
             if (matcher.find() == true)
             { 
                output.setCharAt(i, Character.toUpperCase(output.charAt(i)) );
                continue;
             }

            }
```

A nice, quick 101 on regex statements and how to compose them would also be well appreciated

Comment: You should review the other parts of your code as well. The loop as a whole does not make much sense.

Comment: I'll suggest to use StringBuilder

Comment: Why is it +2 in length_of_names ?

Comment: Are you trying to get the forname and surname from some object `Director`, assemble them into a new string with the surname first, the forename last, separated by a comma and a space, and then turn it all into uppercase?

Comment: An important side note: never compare a boolean, it looks very bad and is a potential for errors. Replace `if (matcher.find() == true)` with `if (matcher.find())`

Comment: *A nice, quick 101 on regex statements and how to compose them would also be well appreciated* Don't ask for a tutorial, especially don't ask for a tutorial on a subject as complex as regular expressions.

Comment: @Lokesh accounts for the comma and space between names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: This answer makes lots of assumptions. Purpose of answer is to show problems with code in question, which is relevant even if assumptions are wrong.*

Assumptions:

1. Value of `forename` is same as returned by `Director.getForename()`.
2. Value of `surname` is same as returned by `Director.getSurname()`.
3. Value of `output` at time of `matcher(...)` call is as shown earlier.
4. `Director.toString()` is implemented as `return surname + ", " + forename;`. Exact implementation doesn't matter, but rest of answer assumes this implementation.
5. For purpose of illustration, `forename = "John"` and `surname = "Doe"`.

Now, lets go thru the code and see what's going on:

```
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer(forename + ", " + surname);
```

Value of `output` is now `"John, Doe"` (9 characters).

```
int length_of_names = Director.getSurname().length() + Director.getForename().length() + 2;
```

Value of `length_of_names` calculates to `9`.

This could be done better using `int length_of_names = output.length()`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b([A-Z][a-z]*)\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(output.append(Director));
```

The string returned by `Director.toString()` (`"Doe, John"`) is appended to `output`, resulting in value being `"John, DoeDoe, John"`. That value is given to the matcher.

With that regex pattern, the matcher will find `"John"`, and `"John"`. It will not find `"DoeDoe"`, since that has an uppercase letter in the middle.

Result is that `find()` returns `true` twice, and all subsequent calls will return `false`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < length_of_names; i++)
{
    if (matcher.find() == true)
    { 
        output.setCharAt(i, Character.toUpperCase(output.charAt(i)) );
        continue;
    }
}
```

Loop iterate 9 times, with values of `i` from `0` to `8` (inclusive).

First two iterations enters the `if` statement, so code will uppercase first two characters in `output`, resulting in value `"JOhn, DoeDoe, John"`.

The `continue` statement has no effect, since loop continues anyway.

**OOPS!!**

That is not what code should do. So, to fix it:

- Don't append `Director` to `output`.
- Don't iterate 9 times. Instead, iterate until `find()` returns `false`.
- Use position of the found text to locate the character to uppercase.

That makes code look like this:

```
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer(forename + ", " + surname);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b([A-Z][a-z]*)\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(output);
while (matcher.find()) {
    int i = matcher.start();
    output.setCharAt(i, Character.toUpperCase(output.charAt(i)));
}
```

Of course, the code is still totally meaningless, since you matched words starting with uppercase letter, so changing the first letter to uppercase will do nothing at all.

Comment: after implementing your code it still does not capitalize the first words of my string buffer, that said this has still been insightful regarding my mistakes